# Firebase Query get random data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can get my user list from firebase with this code;

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>().setQuery(query.orderByChild("name"), User.class).build();
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserHolder>(options)
{
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(final UserHolder holder, int position, User model) {
        final String userid = getRef(position).getKey();
        holder.setHolder(userid);
    }

    @Override
    public UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user, parent, false);
        return new UserHolder(UsersActivity.this, view, getApplicationContext());
    }
};
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to list my users randomly.

How Can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The adapters in FirebaseUI will show the items in the order in which they come from the database. It does not have any built in support for re-ordering the items in the client.

The most likely solution I can think of here is to write your own adapter.